# d3 v4 smoothing line using curve

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, charts

I have the following line:

[image]

I tried smoothening the line using the curve functions:

JS:

```
const line = d3
  .line()
  .curve(d3.curveMonotoneY)
  .x(d => x(d[0]))
  .y(d => y(d[1]));
```

CSS:

```
.line {
  stroke-width: 1px;
  fill: none;
  // shape-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}
```

But no matter what type of curve I try to use the line doesnt seem to change. Do I miss something?

Comment: I guess you have too many points in that line. Can you share the data array?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado that is true, the data array is kinda huge

Comment: So, you have your answer. **No** curve will work here.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I see, thank you, I will try to omit some values.

Comment: This answer of mine at Code Review, apparently unrelated, may give you an explanation of why you'll have to delete some data points: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/171946/143592